# redirect *.php to *.html through .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page like contact.php

When a user type a url like **mydomain.com/contact.php**

Can i possible to reirect browser url to contact.html and the browser shows contact.php's content

**I need redirect all .php to .html and shows the corresponding php files.
User view it like as an html(.html) page**

Is it possible?

I have used **RewriteRule ^/(.*).html $1.php** 
It is only redirect to corresponding php files but user type mydomain.com/contact.php it does not change the browser url to mydomain.com/contact.html

Comment: Surely the rule should be the other way round, like: `RewriteRule ^/(.*).php $1.html` ?

Comment: Just... why?? This makes no sense at all. I don't see any advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two rules for this. The first one performs the 301 redirect to the `.html` file, and the second one gets the data from the `.php` file.

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```